# How to 'define' value in Assumptions but not let Simplify replace it?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I want to let `Simplify` know the exact value of a symbol, to resolve logical statements, but don't want it to actually replace it. For instance, I would like something like

```
assumptions = x==4;  
Simplify[Sqrt[x^2], assumptions]
```

to output x and not 4 (or `Abs[x]`).

How can this, or something analogous, be done?

**Edit:** It wasn't clear enough that I understand that in this case an assumption like `x>0` would output what I want -- however, this is not what I'm looking for. This is what I have been doing so far, but it is messy and needs focused attention. That is, I need to be sure that the `eps` that I set to define a range as

```
assumptions = (x > xValue - eps) && (x < xValue + eps)
```

is small enough for every independent simplification to be equivalent to that of

```
assumptions = x == xValue
```

Even if I could generaly chose a value exaggeratedly small such that this would be the case for all my problems, I'd still like to find a better alternative -- if there is one.

Comment: If instead of the exact value, you provide a range of values (for instance `3<x<5`), the simplification will be done, but the values will not be substituted.

Comment: @yarchik That is what I have been doing in this situation, but have always wondered if there isn't a more elegant and general solution.

Comment: At the risk of pointing the obvious, these [three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4n47.png) examples are from the doc page on `Simplify`.

Comment: @Syed I understand that! It's just that it would be preferable to define the exact value because in very complicated scenarios, with a lot of variables, there is no direct way of defining a safe range for the variable in such a way that the expression is simplified to the max.

Comment: That is, there is no automatic way to find a maximum eps such that the range xValue-eps<x<xValue+eps is equivalent to x==xValue

Comment: May I ask if you can do a replace `/.`  prior to the simplification if you know the exact value?

Comment: @Syed The thing is that I need to see the analytical expression in terms of this meaningful quantities -- mostly because that is how what I'm looking at is normally presented.

Comment: Would `x <=4 && x>=4` work for you?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Never thought of it. This appears to be what I'll do on a regular basis now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to mimic the behavior of symbolic constants like [`Pi`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pi), [`E`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/E), etc:

```
N[x, _] ^= 4;
NumericQ[x] ^= True;
```

Then:

```
Sqrt[x^2]
```

> x

without even using [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify).